# Flex/AS3 multiple state itemrenderers question

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, itemrenderer

I have created a  module with 3 states as an itemrenderer. The states are called Movies, Songs and TvShows. The base state is empty. The itemRenderer consists of Hbox, Vboxes and labels.

And I have created a List component.

What I want to do is to populate data in my List component and make it visible using my ItemRenderer. Depending on the data that is pulled out from the database I want to show the itemRenderer's correct state. Hence if the record pulled out from the database is a song, I want to display the Song state, if it is a movie, I want to show the Movie state and so on.

So depending on the data that's pulled out, I would like to change the current state of itemrenderer. How would i do that?
Can anybody show me an example how i would make this code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

override the `set data` method of your CustomItemRenderer and assign the appropriate state based on the data.

```
override public function set data(value:Object):void
{
  super.data = value;
  if(data.type == "song")
    this.currentState = SONG_STATE;
  else if(data.type == "movie")
    this.currentState = MOVIE_STATE;
  else if //and so on...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks it worked well.
The Only thing i notice was that:

```
this.currentState = MOVIE_STATE;
```

should be

```
this.currentState = "MOVIE_STATE";
```

thanks

DJ

Answer (score 0):

with the above option you need to adjust all your data by looping trough your data arraycollection and setting the type to another state name.

Perhaps a better solution is looping trough all items of the list and change the state;

```
private function changeItemrendererState():void
    {
        var item:mycustomitemrenderer;

        for(var i:uint = 0; i < itemlist.numElements; i++)
        {
            item = itemlist.getElementAt(i) as mycustomitemrenderer;

            item.currentState = "mynewstate";
        }
    }
<s:Scroller focusEnabled="false" hasFocusableChildren="true">   
        <s:DataGroup dataProvider="{mydata}"  itemRenderer="skins.mycustomitemrenderer"  width="100%" height="100%" id="itemlist">
            <s:layout>
                <s:TileLayout horizontalGap="2" verticalGap="2" columnAlign="justifyUsingWidth"/>
            </s:layout>
        </s:DataGroup>
</s:Scroller>
```

This will not work if you use useVirtualLayout="true" it then would only affect the visible items.